# How do I get JSON results in Browser from API Webhook to Telegram Bot

Tags: json, telegram-bot, tradingview-api, telegram-webhook

I'm sending a Tradingview alert to a Telegram bot via webhook. The Tradingview alert message is in JSON format.

I get the alert message in my Telegram bot. What do I need to do see the JSON data in a browser.

I thought using this command with my bot father token would work, but it didn't.
[https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_father_token}/getUpdates](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7Bbot_father_token%7D/getUpdates)